# Gap in table cells when using Ease and scaling

Tags: html, css

In this example [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5hxyf1jb/) I have a table that when you hover over a row, it expands. How do I stop the white gaps from appearing in it?

Edit: I've posted the html below along with the CSS being used. This should be enough to go with. If not please use the Fiddle link from above.

***Edit: This seems to be a chrome only issue and doesn't seem present in Firefox. Does anyone know a workaround for chrome?***

Html:

```
<table class="table-styled">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Test 2</th>
            <th>Test 3</th>
            <th>Test 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
            <td>Test Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
h1, table.table-styled {
    text-align: center;
}
table.table-styled {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 2px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.table-styled th, table.table-styled td {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
table.table-styled tr {
    background: #fefefe;
}
table.table-styled tr, table.table-styled td {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
table.table-styled tr:first-child {
    background: #c0c0c0;
}
table.table-styled tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}
table.table-styled tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);
    position: relative;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Post the html as well please.

Comment: @Peanut The html is present in the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry just wouldn't let me post just the link, made more sense to put it just in fiddle

Comment: @Tarun : Post the code anyway. Not everyone likes to open the fiddles. And read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: @Peanut apologies, i've posted the code up. It's just a demo of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this problem occurs for me only in the fiddle. I tested this using an html file and it worked fine, with no white gaps.

Try it out for yourself and let me know if you have any further problems.

EDIT: Try changing your css to this:

```
h1, table.table-styled {
text-align: center;
}

table.table-styled {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto 2px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table-styled th, table.table-styled td {        
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

table.table-styled tr {
    background: #fefefe;
}


table.table-styled tr, table.table-styled td {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

    table.table-styled tr:first-child {
        background: #c0c0c0;
    }

    table.table-styled tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #e3e3e3;
    }

    table.table-styled tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1, 1);
   -moz-transform:scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1, 1);
     -o-transform:scale(1, 1);
        transform:scale(1, 1);
    position: relative;
        -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }
```

I have changed `transform:scale(1.1, 1.1);` to `transform:scale(1, 1);` and it works fine now.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hxyf1jb/1/)

Comment: Hi, i'm actually getting the problem on a site we've got. I just put a fiddle example together to show the issue.

Comment: @Philiop I have edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi, this does stop it but it also stops the scaling. Scaling of 1 to 1 in this case which is nothing. I'm wanting to resolve the issue once it's grown